# Setting VIM for 256 colors

Tags: vim, terminal, color-scheme, raspbian, 256color

I've googled it for hours but I can't find a solution.
I use raspian, on a raspberry pi and I want to have colorscheems work on it.
Default terminal in raspian seems to be set at 8 colors as when I enter

```
tput colors
```

I get 8.
I'm sure there must be a way to have the term work with 256 colors but I don't know how. Anyway I set tmux in the config file to support 256 colors, so I created a .tmux.conf file in my home directory and have

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

now if I check with tput within tmux I get 256.
Anyway I know you can set VIM to force think you support 256 color by adding

```
set t_Co=256
```

but this seems to make no actual change.
If I run this color test

```
:runtime syntax/colortest.vim
```

in normal terminal from raspian I get only 8 different colors. If I do this on tmux I get more but not all of them because some of them (red and lightred for example) still look the same.

Comment: Do you work on the pi directly or via SSH? If directly, do you use a desktop environment? If yes, what terminal emulator do you use? If not, you'll probably never get 256 colors. Also, you usually don't need to add `set t_Co=256` to your `~/.vimrc` if you have `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in `~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: I have raspian installed on the raspberry pi, downloaded zsh and istalled it. Then have pi hdmi connected to my monitor and a keyboard to work on it. Also have installed x. That's it. No more stuff just really row raspian. I don't now what terminal I use....

Comment: If I do it via ssh on my mac it works... Does rasp terminal not support colors at all? 'couse that would be the solution...

Comment: Did you tried 'set term=xterm-256color'

Comment: Yes but no result... I think it is probably because I am not using any terminal emulator but the raw raspian terminal which probably doesn't support 256 colors... I tried to googled it but I didn't find a how many colors it supports.

Answer (score 4):

did you add `set t_Co=256` *after* the line `colorscheme <yourColourScheme>`?  That was a problem I had early on.

Let me know if you're still having trouble, because I managed to solve a similar problem (only I'm using MobaXterm and GNU screen), and wouldn't mind the excuse to dig into this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and have solved it with the following setup. .zshrc on my OSX laptop contains:

`TERM=xterm-256color`

after I ssh into raspbian, `tput colors` returns 256. On raspbian, I don't have TERM explicitly set (which means it pulls it from ssh), and have the following in .tmux.conf:

`set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`

Then after I do `tmux` (and I don't even need the -2), `tputs colors` still reports 256 colors and vim looks right. I am using vanilla solarized with no edits in .vimrc or elsewhere in the vim configs.